# How to make searching in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a string like below.

```
const a = "The school is big."
```

And I want to make searching function.

```
function searching(q){
    ...
}

// searching(the) -> true
// searching(e s) -> true
// searching(oolis) -> true
// searching(the big) -> false
```

Could you recommend some solution for this case?

Comment: `return a.includes(q)`

Comment: You can use `.includes()` if you remove the spaces from your strings

Comment: You could use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: `oolis` is not in the string, why would that be returning `true`? Is this a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the spaces from both your input string and search string using [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), and convert both to lower case using [`toLowerCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase), then you can use the [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method to check if your search string falls within your input string:

```js
const a = "The school is big.";

function searching(str, q) {
  const str_no_space = str.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
  const q_no_space = q.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
  return str_no_space.includes(q_no_space);
}

console.log(searching(a, "the")); // -> true
console.log(searching(a, "e s")); // -> true
console.log(searching(a, "oolis")); // -> true
console.log(searching(a, "the big")); // -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `includes()` and `toUpperCase()` for case insensitive string comparison.

```js
const a = "The school is big."

function searching(q){
   return a.toUpperCase().includes(q.toUpperCase());
}

console.log(searching('the'));
console.log(searching('e s'));
console.log(searching('oolis'));
console.log(searching('the big'));
```